# How do I validate celery beat schedule with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

Given a celery beat schedule in the Django settings file, how can you test that the dictionary is valid without actually running the tasks or waiting for the schedule?

Consider:

```py
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "task_1": {  # Daily 7:30am UTC
        "schedule": crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
        "task": "valid_path.task_1",
        "options": {"queue": "celery_1"},
    },
    "task_2": {
        "schedule": crontab(minute=1, hour=0),
        "task": "invalid_path.task_1",
        "options": {"queue": "celery_2"},
    },
    "task_3": {
        "schedule": crontab(minute=2, hour=0),
        "task": "valid_path.task_3",
        "options": {"invalid_option": "value"},
    },
}
```

The test should not run any of the tasks and should fail because of either the invalid path or invalid option provided above. If the entire schedule dictionary is valid it should succeed.

Here is a simple attempt, however it relies on calling celery internals and the task is still not mocked correctly.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

import os
import pytest
import copy
from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings
from celery.beat import ScheduleEntry, Scheduler


def test_beat_schedule():
    app = Celery("config.settings")

    scheduler = Scheduler(app, copy.deepcopy(settings.CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE))

    for task_name, task_config in settings.CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE.items():
        # TODO how to mock the actual calling of the task?
        with patch(task_config["task"] + ".run", MagicMock()):
            entry = ScheduleEntry(name=task_name, **task_config)
            print("task", task_config["task"])
            scheduler.apply_entry(entry)
```

Comment: Adding this related github issue: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6953.